# How can I get e.offsetX on mobile/iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, events

There was no offsetX in e.touches[0] when I tried on iPad. Does anyone know where I can get this value of offsetX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use clientX or pageX, see [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/07/touching-and-gesturing-on-iphone-android-and-more/)

Comment: yeah, I see , thank you. And I found a way to get e.offsetX.   
e.offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX - e.touches[0].target.offsetLeft;
e.offsetY = e.touches[0].pageY - e.touches[0].target.offsetTop;
I think it's the same as e.offsetX

Comment: This doesn't take into account any transforms on the element, like rotations or scaling, like offsetX does. offsetX gives the coordinates in the element's local coordinate system, before transformations, it seems.

Answer (score 18):

The correct answer based on the comments in the suggested answer:

```
e.offsetX = e.touches[0].pageX - e.touches[0].target.offsetLeft;     
e.offsetY = e.touches[0].pageY - e.touches[0].target.offsetTop;
```

This ignores any transformations such as rotations or scaling. Also be sure to check if there are any touches.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, @Kontiki - this is the solution that finally fixed things for me:

```
if("touchmove" == e.type)
{

    let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    currX = e.touches[0].clientX - r.left;
    currY = e.touches[0].clientY - r.top;
}
else
{
    currX = e.offsetX;
    currY = e.offsetY;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The page - offset / client approach did not work for me. There was still an offset. I found this other solution that works perfectly:

```
let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

let x = e.touches[0].pageX - r.left;
let y = e.touches[0].pageY - r.top;
```

Answer (score 1):

Was having similar issue on binding event-handler using jQuery's `.on` function on `canvas` element (Don't know the reason).

I resolved it by binding event-handler using `addEventListener`. The `event` object in the handler has offsetX and offsetY defined with proper values.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Can you go into more detail?

Comment: @tremby What specific would you like to know?

Comment: I just don't understand your answer. As far as I can tell `Touch` objects don't have `offsetX` and `offsetY`, at least according to the specification. Your answer suggests that you do get them and I'm wondering how.