# Adjust size of drawing canvas with position absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a drawing canvas. It works but when i draw, the line and mouse is not on the same line/not sync. The line is drawn further from the mouse cursor. If I remove the position:relative from container-whiteboard, then it works fine but the issue is, the canvas fills the entire screen and I could draw anywhere on the screen.

[image: drawing canvas]

```
<div class="container-whiteboard">
    <canvas class="whiteboard" ></canvas>
    <div class="colors">
        <div class="color black"></div>
        <div class="color red"></div>
        <div class="color green"></div>
        <div class="color blue"></div>
        <div class="color yellow"></div>
        <div class="color white"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.container-whiteboard{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
.whiteboard {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.colors {
   position: fixed;
}
</style>
<script>
        var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('whiteboard')[0];
    var colors = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var current = {
        color: 'black'
    };
    var drawing = false;

    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', throttle(onMouseMove, 10), false);
    
    //Touch support for mobile devices
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onMouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchcancel', onMouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', throttle(onMouseMove, 10), false);

    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
        colors[i].addEventListener('click', onColorUpdate, false);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
    onResize();

    function drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, color, emit){
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x0, y0);
        context.lineTo(x1, y1);
        context.strokeStyle = color;
        if(color == 'white')
            context.lineWidth = 20;
        else
            context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();

        if (!emit) { return; }
        var w = canvas.width;
        var h = canvas.height;

        channel.whisper('drawingEvent',{
            x0: x0 / w,
            y0: y0 / h,
            x1: x1 / w,
            y1: y1 / h,
            color: color
        })
        console.log('drawing');
    }

    function onMouseDown(e){
        drawing = true;
        current.x = e.clientX||e.touches[0].clientX;
        current.y = e.clientY||e.touches[0].clientY;
    }

    function onMouseUp(e){
        if (!drawing) { return; }
        drawing = false;
        drawLine(current.x, current.y, e.clientX||e.touches[0].clientX, e.clientY||e.touches[0].clientY, current.color, true);
    }

    function onMouseMove(e){
        if (!drawing) { return; }
        drawLine(current.x, current.y, e.clientX||e.touches[0].clientX, e.clientY||e.touches[0].clientY, current.color, true);
        current.x = e.clientX||e.touches[0].clientX;
        current.y = e.clientY||e.touches[0].clientY;
    }

    function onColorUpdate(e){
        current.color = e.target.className.split(' ')[1];
    }

    // limit the number of events per second
    function throttle(callback, delay) {
        var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
        return function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime();

        if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
            previousCall = time;
            callback.apply(null, arguments);
        }
        };
    }

    function onDrawingEvent(data){
        console.log(2);
        var w = canvas.width;
        var h = canvas.height;
        drawLine(data.x0 * w, data.y0 * h, data.x1 * w, data.y1 * h, data.color);
    }

    function onResize() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: By making the `.whiteboard` `absolute` with `100%` width and height, its ignoring the `container-whiteboard`'s container, could u try to make the `.whiteboard` `relative`?

Comment: set `height` and `width` in canvas with `relative` position

Comment: Could you show us the relevant JavaScript where you work out the cursor position. Also, is this to work on a touch screen as well as with mouse?

Comment: to my understanding it should work fine because the parent-element is relative, the position: absolute should not ignore the container. Try to remove bottom: 0; and right: 0; from the whiteboard. top and left with height + width should be enough if you want to use position: absolute.

Comment: also i agree with A Haworth here. We need more of your code. This might not be a CSS problem

Comment: I've added the JS for reference. thanks @AHaworth

Comment: also @Warden330

Comment: I think you should add width and height as an attribute to `canvas` because if you scale it in css the `canvas` is stretching. (you can also do it with js: `canvas.width = window.innerWidth`)

Comment: you are using a variable called "channel" that is not getting defined anywhere in the code you provided, are there parts missing from the JS or do you have any other libraries than Bootstrap and JQuery added?

Comment: no. channel is just a websocket i used with socket.io. It doesnt effect the canvas drawing @Warden330

Answer (score 1):

The problem of malalignment is caused by using clientX/Y to get the mouse position.

clientX/Y gives position relative to the window. So when your canvas filled the window as it does when you set it absolute then the position within the window and within the canvas are the same so it works.

However, when the canvas is positioned relatively the X/Y within the canvas are different from those in the window.

You need to draw in terms of canvas coordinates so use event.offsetX/Y instead.

Note for touch screens things are a bit more complicated because there is no offsetX/Y in the touches array. Instead you have to do a bit of calculation

```
let r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
currX = e.touches[0].clientX - r.left;
currY = e.touches[0].clientY - r.top;
```

See the discussion in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287877/how-can-i-get-e-offsetx-on-mobile-ipad`some of which is not general enough, but the most recent answer from @fiffy should be OK.